# There is a table with column Product and it has 2 fields laptop and desktop. I need to interchange there values

Tags: sql

There is a table with column name Product and it has 2 values laptop and desktop. I need to interchange there values which means laptop should be Desktop and vice versa.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please explain with an example what you want to achieve. You talk about 'fields', do you mean 'columns'?

Comment: Never any other values?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two lines by using a `CASE` expression with the `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET Product = CASE WHEN Product = 'laptop' THEN 'desktop' ELSE 'laptop' END
```

Answer (score -1):

do this..

```
UPDATE product
SET laptop = desktop, 
desktop= laptop
```

Comment: Note that - UPDATE table SET X = Y, Y = X is the standard way of doing it in SQL, only MySQL misbehaves.

Comment: The column is product. The values are laptop and desktop.

Comment: please explain your question more clearly that means colunm or field what you want to swap??

Comment: if you wont to swap two value in single colunm then you can use.


UPDATE table_name
SET product = ( CASE WHEN product = 'laptop' THEN 'desktop' ELSE 'laptop' END )